# Have 20 views to inflate plus a footer view in recycler view in Android, but recycler view is inflating 19 views plus the footer view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

The ArrayList contains 20 items and I want to show contents from arraylist to the recycler view with 20 views plus I want to add a footer view. But I am getting 19 views and the footer. Here is the code of the Adapter class of Recycler View. If I am increasing size of getItemCount, I am getting indexoutofBound Exception in BindViewHolder Method. Please resolve.

```
Result movie;
UrlConstants urlConstants = UrlConstants.getSingletonRef();
private ArrayList<Result> moviesList = new ArrayList<>();
private Context context;
private final int VIEW_ITEM = 0;
private final int VIEW_PROG = 1;
Fragment fragment;

public MoviesAdapter(ArrayList<Result> moviesList,Fragment fragment) {
    this.moviesList = moviesList;
    this.fragment = fragment;
}


public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public ImageView backdrop_image;
    public TextView title, date;
    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        backdrop_image = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.backdrop_image);
        title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date);
    }
}

public class FooterViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    public TextView tag_text,previous_page,next_page,between_text;

    public FooterViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        between_text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.between_text);
        tag_text = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tag_text);
        previous_page = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.previous_page);
        next_page = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.next_page);

    }
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (isPositionItem(position))
        return VIEW_ITEM;
    return VIEW_PROG;
}

private boolean isPositionItem(int position) {
    return position != getItemCount() -1;
}


@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    context = parent.getContext();

    if (viewType == VIEW_ITEM) {
        View v =  LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.movie_list_row, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(v);
    } else if (viewType == VIEW_PROG){
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.footer_layout, parent, false);
        return new FooterViewHolder(v);
    }

    return null;
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {


    if (holder instanceof MyViewHolder)
    {
        movie = moviesList.get(position);
        ((MyViewHolder)holder).title.setText(movie.getTitle());
        ((MyViewHolder)holder).date.setText(movie.getReleaseDate());
        String url = urlConstants.URL_Image + movie.getBackdropPath();
        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(url)
                .into(((MyViewHolder)holder).backdrop_image);
    }

    else if (holder instanceof FooterViewHolder)
    {
        movie = moviesList.get(position);


        ((FooterViewHolder)holder).tag_text.setText("Viewing " + movie.getPage() + " of " + movie.getTotal_pages() + " Pages" );
        ((FooterViewHolder)holder).previous_page.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                ((MoviesMainFragment)fragment).prepareOnlineData(movie.getPage() - 1);
            }
        });
        ((FooterViewHolder)holder).next_page.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ((MoviesMainFragment)fragment).prepareOnlineData(movie.getPage() + 1);
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount()
{
    return this.moviesList.size();
}
```

Comment: does `isPositionItem()` return the position of the footer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to increase the movilist size by 1. To do that, you have to insert a dummy data into the last item of the list so that the last item doesn't have null data and you don't get Indexoutofbound.

No need to increase size getItemCount, you have already added dummy item in the list so.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**

this line

```
return position != getItemCount() -1;
```

You have 20 items, i.e. item0..item19. The above will check for only 19 items, i.e. upto item18. When the recycler view reaches the last position, based on the condition it will inflate the footer view and thus ignores the last item.

**Solution**

Below code works for me.

Change your `isPositionItem()` method like below

```
private boolean isPositionItem(int position) {
    return position == moviesList.size();
}
```

Change your `getItemCount()` like below

```
@Override
public int getItemCount()
{
   return this.moviesList.size()+1;
}
```

Comment: This solution is giving Index out of bound exception at                          
movie = moviesList.get(position); in MyViewholder instance